# Screenshare daemon on lan?

Tags: windows, linux, lan, remote-access, screen-capture

I was thinking about getting a kiosk or two i thought since monitors are facing potential customers and we'll be behind a table i'd be hard to see if something gone wrong/needs our attention. It would also be nice to watch them and what their looking at or doing when they are interested or frustrated

How might i capture all the machines screen on my own? i'd need somekind of daemon in the background. I may have VMs so i'd either need it to work on the OS capturing what is shown in the VM or have it installed on each VM. My machine would likely be windows.

Do you know of any good solutions?
I dont need to take over and control the screen but that may be nice since i wouldnt need to walk around to fix something.

Answer (score 0):

Try TightVNC:

http://www.tightvnc.com/

It's free (and open source).  You would install the server on each public machine, and then you could use the client to check in on each one as needed.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution would be to use a video splitter box to send a duplicate signal to a second monitor. No software required, and they are relatively inexpensive.